# Qlist suitable for use in service?

Tags: c++, qt, memory, qlist

I am creating a C++ program that will run as a service (under linux), and I'm using Qt because of the numerous handy methods.  I'm using a QList to track items that will add to, and remove from, the qlist over many months.  (With potentially hundreds of additions/removals per day).

Based on my recent reading, it appears that QList's never shrink - they only grow in terms of memory usage (until the entire QList is deallocated).  Does that make a QList unsuitable for use in an app that runs indefinitely?

Will I have to create my own linked list instead?  Or is there a way to "shrink"/cleanup the memory used in a QList?

---

Update: Based on feedback below is QLinkedList is preferable?  (Does it immediately release memory when a member of the list is "erased")

Comment: Yikes!  Did not know this about QList.  Where have you read that?

Comment: QList's are a feature of Qt (a C++ library)

Comment: @laser_wizard it says so in the documentation, however QList uses a `T*[]` (array of pointers to T) to store the data so it's not all that bad

Comment: looks like @ratchetfreak has some good info :)

Comment: Did you actually measure the memory use of `QList` and identified it as something you need to worry about, or is this just cargo cult programming? On a platform with 64 bit pointers, as a rule of thumb `QList` has about 1kByte of overhead per 100 large items (larger than 8 bytes). This overhead scales with the peak number of items stored at once in the list. So, for example, if you ever store no more than 1000 items in the list, the overhead won't ever exceed 10kBytes. I think worrying about it is a waste of time. If you claim otherwise, share with us how you measured and what the results are.

Comment: I have no idea what 'cargo cult' programming is.  I'm trying to *avoid* building this the wrong way...as opposed to building it incorrectly, finding out of control memory growth, tracing to Qlist, and then asking questions.  In this case, the items in the list are constantly rotating in & out, so it appears that QList will grow endlessly in size (until the object is destroyed).  QLinkedList will handle the memory better in this case.  (If 'cargo cult' programming means trying to find the best tools for each job, then yes thats me)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qt has it's own QVector and QLinkedList

QVector has a [`squeeze`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qvector.html#squeeze) function that releases unused memory when needed

Comment: From more reading it looks like QVector has a lot of overhead adding/deleting.  (My list my undergo rapid changes).  Since I only append to the end of the list does that make QLinkedList preffered?

Comment: @Michelle depends on where you add to and delete from, there are other [container classes](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/containers.html) implemented in Qt (and also in the standard library of C++)

Comment: I'm still a beginner at Qt so trying to avoid more learning (already overwhelmed with Qt).  I see QLinkedList has no squeeze command, so does that mean it always immediately releases unused memory (upon erase call)?  So that would seem to be the best

Comment: @Michelle QLinkedList immediately releases unused memory

Answer (score 2):

What is the "reading" that gave you the idea about `QList`? If it would never release unused memory, it'd be essentially leaking the memory, and that's not the case.

`QList` is internally implemented as a vector-of-pointers. When the object is small enough to fit in the same number of bytes as a pointer does, the list is equivalent to a `QVector`. The internal vector *maybe* doesn't shrink, but that doesn't matter in practice. It's only 4 or 8 bytes per element, and it's bounded by the total number of items present in the list. It's most likely a red herring.

Comment: Probably the part in the [`QList`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qlist.html#details) documentation that states: `Note that the internal array only ever gets bigger over the life of the list. It never shrinks. The internal array is deallocated by the destructor and by the assignment operator, when one list is assigned to another.`

Comment: @thuga That internal array stores 4-8 bytes per element. It doesn't matter that it never shrinks unless you store really small elements. The storage taken by just a few decently-sized elements will overshadow any space used by the array.

Comment: As I mentioned above, I'm adding & removing hundreds of items per day.  If this service runs for a year it could potentially consume a lot of memory.  (And in general an app which constantly consumes more memory doesn't sound well designed).  The docs also say that adding to a QVector will cause the entire array of elements to be copied to a new array to keep memory consequtive; sounds like a bad fit when constantly adding & removing items).  QLinkedList sounds like the winner here !?

Comment: @Michelle: **No!** The memory overhead scales with *maximum value* of `list->size()`. That's *all*. It doesn't matter how many items you add and remove. You're consuming about `8*list->size()` (on 64 bit pointer platforms) of overhead, and this overhead only grows, never shrinks. So, what counts is not how many items you add or remove, but how many items there are in the list all at once. `QLinkedList` has even higher overhead - at least `24*list->size()`, but this overhead can go down.

Comment: @Michelle: Again, you better had solid measurements to show that it's a problem. Otherwise it's just a waste of time. You want a data structure that's easy to work with. Worry about overheads when your tests show that overheads matter.

Comment: @Michelle: For example, if the list never has more than 1000 items in it all at once, then the overhead is about 16kBytes worst case, no matter how long the list has been in use. If you use a linked list, that overhead will be about 24kBytes worst case, and you get a structure that's harder to use because you can't index it with integers anymore.

Comment: @KubaOber Yes I know. I was just pointing out which part gave OP the idea of `QList` not freeing any memory.